# cleartool error: Unable to rebase stream

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Can't rebase stream to the foundation baseline. Probably the baseline is corrupted.

Is it possible to fix this baseline?

```
cleartool: Error: Version map for baseline is unavailable.
cleartool: Error: Unable to get unlabelled baselines in foundation
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine if configuration is valid
cleartool: Error: Unable to rebase stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you sure to select the right baseline?

If you select a composite baseline, it is per its nature unlabelled.

Second, what version of ClearCase are you using? Is your project a multisite one?

Your error message is seen in the IBM technote "[Creating a child stream in a ClearCase MultiSite environment results in Error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21404796)"

> The root cause for the problem is that `baselinelbtype` on a site where you are creating the stream has got a following postfix:

```
lbtype:<lbtype_name>_in_progress@\<cvob>
```

> whereas the `baselinelbtype` on a site where baseline has been created and it's mastered object is as follows:

```
lbtype:<lbtype_name>@\<cvob>
```

---

You can check out this IBM technote "[Version map for baseline is unavailable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21127820)"

> To confirm this issue, go to a command prompt, change directory (cd) into a UCM view and into the root of the component with the offending baseline.
>
> - Run a `cleartool lsbl -l` and check on each baseline from the bottom up for Label Status, noting those that are unlabelled baselines.
> - Then starting at the oldest unlabelled baseline and working forward, run chbl
> - cleartool chbl -incremental  baseline:@\.
> - This will apply a label status to each unlabelled baseline and will then allow a rebase of a child stream.

Comment: recommended latest baseline on the int stream and rebased.